# Regression: Explaining increase in revenue from explanatory variables

Tags: regression

My boss has an ice cream stand on the sea and has asked me to explain different factors contribute to the revenue of the stand.

Each month my boss produces a revenue expectation. We if we miss the target he'd like me to explain how three factors contributed to the difference between the expectation and the realized result.

There are three external factors that affects the revenue of the ice cream stand.
1) improvements in the ice cream formula.
2) the total ice cream sales per month for the whole area.
3) how many days with high waves.

From historical data I know that the correlation between revenue and "2" is about 50% and the correlation between revenue and "3" is about 27%.

Let's say my boss expects ice cream stand to have $100  of revenue for December and when December ends the stand made 110.

My boss will then ask me "how much of increase in revenue can be explained by the increase in (for instance) the difference between the projected total ice cream sales and the actual sales?
(And similar for the number of high wave days).

Initially I thought I could just regress the the revenue and "3" for instance on "2" to answer that question, but I think I am missing an elegant/simple solution.

Many thanks,

Comment: How long of a time series do you have? Can you post a plot of your data?

Comment: I have about 1500 points. I am not near the office at the moment, so I cannot post a plot of the data. However, basically it is just regular data - no outliers etc. etc. I suppose my boss would also need to supply some estimates of "2" and "3".

Comment: A plot would summarise a number of things that would help point you towards the best analytical approach. Currently, you have stated a couple of things that seem inconsistent and would be clarified by such a plot: (1) you said your data is monthly, and (2) you've mentioned that you have 1500 points, which would suggest that your stand has been running for 1500 / 12 = 125 years.

Comment: Regression with auto-correlated time series data is normally (ALWAYS !) bad practice. http://autobox.com/dave/regvsbox.pdf (which I authored) discusses issues/differences/opportunities/pitfalls when dealing with time series that your possible regression solutions may be ignoring.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Lets assume everything is daily estimates for now (to make it simpler). So if tomorrow I think the total area sales will be 1000 (long term average is 900) and the profit will be $215 (long term average is 200). If we find that the total area sales was 1100, how do I go about attributing the revenue to area sales and ice cream formula improvements?